# Integral of exponential function

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, convex-analysis

Consider $f$ being a measurable function on $R^n$ such that $$\int_{E} e^{|f|}=1$$ ($E$ measurable) and $f$ vanishes outside $E$ . Then $f\in L^p(R^n)$ for all $p\in (0,\infty)$.

I tried using that measure of $E$ cannot be bigger than $1$ and the formulae

$$\int|f|^p=p\int_0^\infty \alpha^{p-1}\omega(\alpha)d\alpha$$

where 
$\omega(\alpha)=\{x \in R^n: |f(x)|>\alpha\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all $x\ge0$, $x<e^x$. Therefore, substituting $x\mapsto x/p$ and raising both sides to the $p^{\text{th}}$ power yields
$$
\left(\frac{x}{p}\right)^p<e^x
$$
Therefore,
$$
\left(\int_E|f(x)|^p\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/p}\le p\left(\int_E e^{|f(x)|}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/p}
$$

Answer (score 2):

For any $p \in (0,\infty)$ there is $c$ such that $e^x \ge c x^p$ for all $x > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

You can in fact prove more. By Beppo-Leví we have
$$\int e^{|f|}d\mu=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}\int|f|^{k}d\mu\geq\frac{||f||_{L^{k}}^{k}}{k!},\; k\in\mathbb{N}$$
hence
$f\in L^{p},\: p\in\mathbb{N}$ and so by interpolation $f\in L^{p},\: p\geq1$

Comment: Good answer but it doesnt give the best constant.

Comment: I didnt read the entire question I thought it said $f\in L^{1}$.
Anyway you can also prove that $f\in L^{p},\: p\in(0,1)$ by noting that $e^{x}\geq x,\: x\geq0$, what constant are you reffering to btw?